# Strange Whitespace Under Display:block Element

Tags: html, css

There is some strange whitespace that keeps appearing under all my display: block elements. It's for a meganavigation. I have no idea what is causing this. Basically, I have the code (plus some more that determines the column widths) below, and when it generates the meganav, the items that are rendered as "display:block" have a space below them. You can also see it when hovering over the items in the main navigation as well. I'm not quite sure what to do.

```
a {
font-family: "Frutiger LT Std 45 Light", sans-serif;
color: black;
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 10px;
display: block;
padding: 3px;

}

a:hover {

text-decoration: none;
color: white;
background-color: #c8a51b;

}

.nav {

background: #1b2c69;
width: 800px;
margin: 10px;
height: 30px;

}

.nav li {

list-style: none;

}

.nav > li {

padding: 0;
float: left;
position: relative;

}

.nav > li > a {

font-family: "Frutiger LT Std 45 Light", sans-serif;
float: left;
color: #fff;
font-size: 13px;
text-decoration: none;
line-height: 30px;
padding: 0 20px;
height: 43px;
text-transform: uppercase;

}

.nav > li:hover > a {
background: #FFF;
color: #1b2c69;

}
```

HTML:

```
<ul class="nav">
<li><a href="#">Home</a>

</li>
<li><a href="#">Our Company</a>

<div class="tab1">
<div class="container-1">
<div class="col1"> <a href="#">Business Reports</a>

 <br> <a href="#">Core Values</a>

 <br> <a href="#">Corp Priority Updates</a>

 <br> <a href="#">Critical Success Factors</a>

 <br> <a href="#">Daily Reports</a>

 <br> <a href="#">EBIT Chart</a>

 <br> <a href="#">HyVisability Scorecard</a>

<br>  <a href="#">Mission Statement</a>

 <br> <a href="#">Quality Vision</a>

 <br> <a href="#">Strategic Vision</a>

 <br>
 </div>
 </div>
 </div>
</li>
```

Comment: Post an [mcve] please.

Comment: I tried to cut out as much as possible, but I'm not sure of what's causing the problem, so I don't want to cut out something that may be affecting the outcome.

Comment: Hey there, can you post your HTML along with your CSS so we can get a better snapshot of what you're working with.

Comment: Your code is not enough to answer. Try debugging, or try removing this line: padding: 3px;

Comment: Might want to put some html so we can recreate the problem. In order to make it even easier to understand your problem make a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: You need to add the HTML to your question.

Comment: Added HTML. Hopefully this helps.

Answer (score 0):

See [this link](http://plnkr.co/edit/AKhuSZ7csmqiCzHPoYKN?p=preview)

I have added bgcolor to background to see the white space.

The fix is:

```
.nav > li > a {

font-family: "Frutiger LT Std 45 Light", sans-serif;
float: left;
color: #fff;
font-size: 13px;
text-decoration: none;
line-height: 30px;
padding: 0 20px;
height: 30px;
text-transform: uppercase;

}
```

In the above css I changed `height: 43px;` to `height: 30px;`

Because the height for all li tags should be same in tour case to achieve what you want. Hope you understand.

Comment: Thank you, but that doesn't solve the large space between the items in the meganav.

Comment: In that case remove <br> tags in col1 div. You don't need them.

Comment: That fixed it. Thank you!